# Buy Button Click Counter

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi and thanks for your time. I have an landing page selling a product ([Wordpress Course, for example](http://cursos7.com.br/landing.php?curso=10)). When someone clicks on the buy button, he´s redirected to a payment service (paypal like).

What i need from you is a simple thing: an idea (or even a clue) on how to count the number of times the submit button (buy button) is clicked.

I can easily imagine how to count page views with PHP, but is it possible to redirect him to the third party and at the same time reload the initial landing page, to execute my SQL Update Query to count one click, or something like this?

Comment: Usually, the link is to one of _your_ pages, does some count update work, and then _redirects_ to a PSP.

Comment: Wrikken, i had something like this on the past, but i was losing sales because of people didn´t wanted to wait for the "1 sec redirect". But if there is not another way, that´s exactly what i´m going to do, again. Thanks!

Comment: tracking clicks is often performed by some sort of analyitcs software such as [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

Comment: @Marco: well, it is your job not to take to long. If it takes >200ms, either there's something seriously wrong with your code (loads an entire framework for a simple update?), your database server, or your hardware is seriously underpowered or overused by the current visitors.

Comment: @Wrikken, got it. Is it possible to redirect someone to a shopping cart that´s triggered by a form submit?

Comment: If it's a GET request you could. Not with a POST requests (there are redirect http status codes for that, but most UA's don't implement them at this point). I also detest having to make the user have to post all kinds of values (which are manipulatable). PSP's that you talk to directly, give you a transactionurl, and just a GET redirect is much preferred. But simply put: if you most efficient script takes N time to update the counter, and you need to navigate the user to another server, it will take at least N time before you can do so, whichever method (ajax, redirect, etc.) you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Ajax. 
When the button is clicked send an AJAX request to a php page just like others have suggested. However since it is asynchronous, your users won't even notice it.

In terms of code you could just send the ajax request, then redirect to the payment page. Easy and done.

EDIT---

To get info on ajax:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: that´s exactly what i´m looking for! Could you please point me some tutorial or directions on how to send this Ajax request to another PHP page?

Comment: @MarcoFloriano have you tried google?

Comment: i've updated my answer with a couple of links. Doing an ajax request is actually very simple. Read through some of the tutorials and post here again if you are having problems.

Answer (score 1):

Have the link go to a page on your end, i.e. `click.php`, that does the SQL update, then redirects to the actual URL you wanted them to wind up on.

Or, just create a bit.ly (or any other URL shortener) URL and use their built-in click tracking for free.

Comment: The destiny is not an ordinary URL. I can´t redirect (or don't know how) because the trigger of the shopping cart is a submit button from a buy form.